# Какие есть средства кроссплатформенного переноса локального кластера minikube с Linux на Windows?

Tags: cluster, kubernetes

Получил задание проанализировать средства кроссплатформенного переноса кластера, написать инструкцию для кластера minikube и провернуть это дело с Linux машины на Windows.
Кластер перенести именно целиком, но как это сделать ни малейшего понятия.
Какие можете посоветовать средства, если такие вообще есть, чтобы это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Миграция кластеров осуществляется следующим образом:-

- нужно 2 кластера
- на кластер 1 устанавливается velero и подключить к minio, создать бэкап (можно создать как бэкап всего кластера, так и отдельных компонентов)
- установить Velero на кластер 2 и подключить к minio
- проверить доступность бэкапа, созданного с кластера 1
- восстановить этот бэкап на кластере 2
  Миграция осуществлена

Как сделать иначе я понял и не нашел информации